# Removing Column Footings

Tags: basement, footings, column

I'm working on a basement renovation, and behind the wall I found the steel columns which I expected, but rather than sitting on the concrete slab like the other exposed one, there is a concrete footing above the slab. Has anyone seen something like this before, and is it safe to chip away or remove and put directly on the slab like the others?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: support the ceiling with another post ... remove this post ... remove the concrete block .... extend the post and reinstall

Comment: The slab may be lower grade concrete, so this distributes the load.  In 60's style homes they used steel plates on slab with teleposts that had to be adjusted from clay shinkage in winter or expansion in summer from poor weaping tile drainage.

Comment: Could what appears to be a concrete block actually be the top of a steel reinforced pier which goes through the slab down into the soil to a more resistant layer of limestone, shale or hard rock? In any case I don't think you should make any changes to this without an engineering report.

Comment: thanks for the comments everyone. I'm in London, ON, Canada and there is no limestone, shale or harder rock around as far as I know. The house was built in the 60's so Tony may be onto something. The only confusing part is that there are 3 posts in the basement - two like this and one just on the slab. The one on the slab has no cracking or issues, so I think I might be good to move and extend as jsotola mentioned.

Comment: Why do you think the builder put two of the posts on raised blocks? What are the lengths of the 3 steel posts? Is the distance from the ceiling beams to the concrete slab the same at all three locations? Could it be that the blocks were needed because two of the three steel posts were simply too short to reach? I have heard of, but not seen, posts with adjustable screw jacks to allow seasonal or progressive adjustment. Do your steel posts have adjusters at the tops?

Comment: Not really sure why it was done. The distance from the slab to beam is the same at all 3 locations, which is about 8'. It's possible that the posts were just too short at the time so a footing was added. The top of the posts all have a smaller threaded post with a hole and rod for adjustment. I figured this was just for original setting of the post.

Comment: Coming back with an update - I added a temporary jack next to one of the existing to hold the weight and took out on of them to see what was going on. from what I could tell, the jack didn't have the adjustable holes low enough on the upper sleeve to accommodate the height, so they had to raise the post on blocks. Simple solution - flip the top sleeve over and now the holes are in the right spot. Easy fix, maybe they just didn't think about it at the time. Thanks for the suggestions guys.